# How to track a variable whose value keeps changing across the entire lifecycle of flask application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, global-variables, flask-appbuilder

I have a **Flask** application which have some endpoints out of which 3 are for managing the **Flask** app. There is a variable **`health_status`** whose value is initially "**UP**" - string.

**/check** = checks the status of the flask app. whether it's up or down.

**/up** = changes the value of a variable to "UP" whose value is used as a check before any request is served

**/down** = changes the value of a variable to "**DOWN**"

When the **`health_status`** is "**UP**" the app can serve any endpoints that it is providing. When it is "**DOWN**", it simply returns **500** error for any API endpoint excep /up endpoint which brings back the server health status (I'm making a check before executing any API call using **`@app.before_request`** in Flask).

What I want to know is if this is preferrable. Is there any alternative for doing such task?

**health_check.py:**

```
from flask.json import jsonify
from app.common.views.api_view import APIView
from app import global_config

class View(APIView):
    def check(self):
        return jsonify({'status': f"Workload service is {global_config.health_status}"})
    def up(self):
        global_config.health_status = "UP"
        return jsonify({'status': "Workload service is up and running"})
    def down(self):
        global_config.health_status = "DOWN"
        return jsonify({'status': f"Workload service stopped"})
```

**global_config.py:**

```
workload_health_status = "UP"
```

**app/__init__.py:**

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from app import global_config
excluded_paths = ['/api/health/up/', '/api/health/down/']

def register_blueprints(app):
    from .health import healthcheck_api
    app.register_blueprint(healthcheck_api, url_prefix="/api/health")

def create_app(**kwargs):
    app = Flask(__name__, **kwargs)
    register_blueprints(app)
    @app.before_request
    def health_check_test():
        if request.path not in excluded_paths and global_config.workload_health_status == "DOWN":
            return jsonify({"status": "Workload service is NOT running"}), 500
    return app
```

Comment: Wouldn't the user be perfectly aware if the app was down simply by allowing it to error normally? How can `/up` or `/check` change anything if the app is actually down?

Comment: I'm just setting a variable whose value is displayed when `/check` endpoint is called. And modifying the variable value when `/up` or `/down` is called. I also need to have a way to bring the app up and serve the APIs after the `/up` endpoint is called.

Comment: Right, but neither of those routes actually work if the app is down

Comment: No. It is working. Because I'm also checking if the path is in `excluded_paths` list in @app.before_request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the app's built-in [config object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/) and query/update it from anywhere in the application, e.g. `app.config['health_status'] = 'UP'`. This would obviate the need for your `global_config` object. Using `@app.before_request` is probably still the most elegant way to check this value though.

Comment: How can I access `app.config['health_status']` in `health_check.py`?

Comment: By using `from flask import current_app as app` and then         `app.config['workload_health_status']`?

Comment: Yes, or you can just reference `current_app.config` directly. No need for an alias.

Comment: got it. Thanks. :-)